# Datapower B2B Transaction Viewer Network Error

Tags: ibm-datapower

We have a setup for an outside company to send us files but on the transaction viewer i'm getting a Network Error in the Result Code column. Said company is reporting a "500 Network Error".

How can I fix this or where can i find more info about this error?

Comment: Too broad. We cannot investigate for you. You need to narrow the problem down.

Comment: Do this messages help?

-The **** AS2 system is reporting an error while attempting to deliver one or more documents to your mailbox.

-Error Description: Error - 500 Error Transfer failed: 500 Error

Comment: I'm also seeing this message in the System log:

0x80c0007b - stylepolicy (b2b-default): No error rule is matched.

Answer (score 0):

We would need debug logs and a packet-capture - not sure if you want to put this in public space, so consider to raise a PMR with IBM Support.